# what makes Jsoup faster than HttpURLConnection & HttpClient in most cases

Tags: java, optimization, jsoup, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I want to compare performances for the three implementations mentioned in the title, I wrote a little JAVA program to help me doing this. The main method contains three blocks of testing, each block looks like this :

```
        nb=0; time=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            double v = methodX(url);
            if(v>0){
                nb++;
                time+=v;
            }
        }
        if(nb==0) nb=1;
        System.out.println("HttpClient : "+(time/ ((double) nb))+". Tries "+nb+"/7");
```

Variable `nb` is used to avoid failed requests. Now method `methodX` is one of :

```
    private static double testWithNativeHUC(String url){
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", UA);
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            while (bufferedReader.readLine()!=null);
            return System.currentTimeMillis()-before;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static double testWithHC(String url) {
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent(UA).build();
            BasicResponseHandler basicResponseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            basicResponseHandler.handleResponse(response);
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private static double testWithJsoup(String url){
        try{
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Jsoup.connect(url).execute().parse();
            return System.currentTimeMillis()-before;
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

What I am getting as output is the following.

for url `https://stackoverflow.com` :

```
    HttpUrlConnection : 325.85714285714283. Tries 7/7
    HttpClient : 299.0. Tries 7/7
    Jsoup : 172.42857142857142. Tries 7/7
```

for url `https://online.vfsglobal.dz` :

```
    HttpUrlConnection : 104.57142857142857. Tries 7/7
    HttpClient : 181.0. Tries 7/7
    Jsoup : 57.857142857142854. Tries 7/7
```

for url `https://google.com/` :

```
    HttpUrlConnection : 251.28571428571428. Tries 7/7
    HttpClient : 259.57142857142856. Tries 7/7
    Jsoup : 299.85714285714283. Tries 7/7
```

for url `https://algeria.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php` :

```
    HttpUrlConnection : 112.57142857142857. Tries 7/7
    HttpClient : 194.85714285714286. Tries 7/7
    Jsoup : 67.42857142857143. Tries 7/7
```

for url `https://tunisia.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php` :

```
    HttpUrlConnection : 439.2857142857143. Tries 7/7
    HttpClient : 283.42857142857144. Tries 7/7
    Jsoup : 144.71428571428572. Tries 7/7
```

Even repeating tests gives same results, I didn't use a sleep time between requests to have rapid results, I believe it has no big impact on results.

**EDIT**
In fact I analysed Jsoup's sources, it shows that it uses HttpURLConnection with BufferedInputStream, I've tried to use both in a HttpURLConnection fashion, but same results, as you can see, the difference is clear and Jsoup appears to be clearly faster than HttpURLConnection and it uses HttpURLConnection !

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Nothing. The code is only as fast as the network and the server response and any intermediate caching. The choice of client can't affect any of those things. Reexamine your data and examine your assumptions.

Comment: In fact I analysed Jsoup's sources, it shows that it uses HttpURLConnection with BufferedInputStream, I've tried to use both in a HttpURLConnection fashion, but same results, as you can see, the difference is clear and Jsoup appears to be clearly faster than HttpURLConnection and it uses HttpURLConnection !

Comment: I'm sorry, but your benchmark is not meaningful. Some factors in Java (JIT, GC, Memory allocation, ...) are not considered. Maybe your results are different when you change the order to Jsoup, HttpClient, HttpUrlConnection. Try Microbenchmark Frameworks like JHM and more tries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Benchmark is not meaningful.

I wrote a microbenchmark for this three libraries and got as result, that there is no significant difference.

```
Benchmark                                     Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
HttpBenchmark.httpClientGoogle                avgt    2  151.162          ms/op
HttpBenchmark.httpClientStackoverflow         avgt    2  151.086          ms/op
HttpBenchmark.httpUrlConnectionGoogle         avgt    2  235.869          ms/op
HttpBenchmark.httpUrlConnectionStackoverflow  avgt    2  145.162          ms/op
HttpBenchmark.jsoupGoogle                     avgt    2  391.162          ms/op
HttpBenchmark.jsoupStackoverflow              avgt    2  188.059          ms/op
```

There are only one small difference between your tests and mine:

- JSoup set header "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" this will reduce bandwidth
- JSoup uses an bigger buffer (32kb)
- Reuse HttpClient is needed

In my tests JSoup is the slowest. Of course only JSoup parses the response.

My Benchmark:

```
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 2, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Threads(1)
public class HttpBenchmark {

    private static final String GOOGLE          = "https://google.com/";
    private static final String STACKOVERFLOW   = "https://stackoverflow.com";

    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    @Benchmark
    public void httpClientGoogle() throws Exception {
        httpClient(GOOGLE);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void httpClientStackoverflow() throws Exception {
        httpClient(STACKOVERFLOW);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void httpUrlConnectionGoogle() throws Exception {
        httpUrlConnection(GOOGLE);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void httpUrlConnectionStackoverflow() throws Exception {
        httpUrlConnection(STACKOVERFLOW);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void jsoupGoogle() throws Exception {
        jsoup(GOOGLE);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void jsoupStackoverflow() throws Exception {
        jsoup(STACKOVERFLOW);
    }

    private void httpClient(final String url) throws Exception {
        final CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        final BasicResponseHandler basicResponseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        basicResponseHandler.handleResponse(response);
        response.close();
    }

    private void httpUrlConnection(final String url) throws Exception {
        final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        try (final BufferedInputStream r = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())) {
            final byte[] tmp = new byte[1024 * 32];
            int read;
            while (true) {
                read = r.read(tmp);
                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void jsoup(final String url) throws Exception {
        Jsoup.connect(url).execute().parse();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what you used to perform these tests ? I want to do more tests with it

Comment: I found out it is JMH, I'll do more tests, thanks for the idea of benchmarking

Comment: Great, it would be awesome if you could accept my answer

Comment: Even by testing more cases I found out same results, Jsoup is faster than HUC for most websites I tested, I think this is duo to some optimization done by Jsoup for HUC, for example connection persisting (cause while testing, many requests are sent to a same website) which I was not using in my HUC test, but not sure JSoup is using it